# How to add label to date buttons on the navigation of Gantt chart highcharts?

Tags: highcharts, react-highcharts, highcharts-gantt

I would like to add labels to the dates input we have in navigation of gantt chart. Something like attached in the image.
[image: Would like to add lebel (from) and remove the circled arrow between two dates]

Also is it possible to change alignment of the yAxis labels (Prototypings, Development & Testing, Testing, Development, etc). I see currently these are left aligned but I want to know if i can customize and make it center/right aligned.

Answer (score 0):

You can overwrite the labels on the `chart.load` event:

**Example code:**

```
  chart: {
    events: {
      load: function() {
        document.getElementsByClassName("highcharts-range-label")[0].firstChild.textContent = "From";
        document.getElementsByClassName("highcharts-range-label")[0].style.transform = 'translate(-30px, 3px)'
      }
    }
  }
```

In the case of the aligning `yAxis.labels` in your example, you can use `category` yAxis type as follows:

```
   yAxis: {
type: 'category',
labels: {
  align: 'center',
  format: '{point.name}'
},
  },

  series: [{
    data: [{
      name: 'Task',
      start: Date.UTC(2017, 11, 1),
      end: Date.UTC(2017, 12, 2),
      y: 0
    }]
  }]
```

**Demo:**
https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/p5syjb6r/

**API Reference:**
https://api.highcharts.com/gantt/xAxis.labels.align